# Android: admob only works in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, admob

I set up admob for one of my apps, and it only recieves ads on my emulator, never on my phone.

Set it up the xml way (http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html), and everything shows up fine when i run the emulator, but as soon as i try it with my phone, it never recieves an ad.

Weird thing is, my admob account has like 1000 request and a 60% fill rate. I can just never see them I guess.

Why do you think it doesnt work on my phone? Thanks

xml to create it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.EricLunty.i90xLITE"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    ads:adUnitId="a14dbddfe120711" ads:adSize="BANNER" android:layout_height="50dip" android:layout_width="320dip"/>
<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/mainList"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

attrs xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
    <attr name="adSize">
        <enum name="BANNER" value="1" />
        <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2" />
        <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3" />
        <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4" />
    </attr>
    <attr name="adUnitId" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

calls this during oncreate()

```
adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Comment: Whats the error/description in LogCat?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing, 
ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 2B8B585F92C97612132BB9768B2208A8"
in your xml.When you install the app in real devices.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks clean.  It is likely that you have an Ad Blocker on your phone.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but then i added a house ad that is used to fill all empty space. Since that one doesn't show up on my phone, i don't really get whats going on.

Comment: Is the resolution of your phone unusually small?  What phone do are you using?

Comment: galaxy s captivate, so i'm sure its fine.

Comment: Quite right.  Can you test it on a friend's phone?  Also, run `adb logcat` on your phone and see if there is an error message from AdMob - that might shed some light on the issue.

Comment: sorry, android noob here, but it just says "unable to open log device /dev/log/main: no such file or directory" when i do that

Comment: Make sure your phone has USB Debugging checked (probably in Settings->Applications->Development). Once set, shut down any running emulator and try the 'adb logcat' again

Comment: Ah, no can do. Im running firefly 3.0 rom so logging is disabled. Perhaps thats why i cant see the ads as well.

Comment: Maybe you have an Ad Block app installed, or it could be installed by default on that rom.  The rom, however, should allow for you to enable debugging.

Comment: maybe. i got a different rom that has logs, and the logcat gives me a "ioexception connection to ad url", and that the connection was refused. So its probably some built in ad blocker.

Comment: I have updated my answer to properly answer your question.  You can check the "checkmark" beside my answer so other people know it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

After ours of searching and braining i discovered that test ads are shown only on devices where language is set to English!!

On my Nexus 7 and on an emulator running 4.3 ads were shown (both set to English), while on my Nexus S and on another emulator running 2.3.3 didn't (both set to italian).

When i set them to english they worked.

But, i don't know how to make it work on non-english devices!

Hope this helps.